# Updating the item value in the array, and how can I append the item instead of overwriting it?

Tags: php

I created a shopping cart, and whenever there is an item, I will increase the quantity. And if the item is not in the  cart, I am pulling the information of the item from the database. However, the while loop keeps overwriting the SESSION variable instead of appending it. This is my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['bookId'])) {
        $bookId = $_GET['bookId'];
        if (isset($_SESSION['cartItems'])) {
            echo "cart NOT empty";
            $cartItems = $_SESSION['cartItems'];

            // Loop through the cartItems array.
            $found = 0;
               
                foreach ($cartItems as &$cartItem) {
                    // If the book is already in the cart items
                    if ($cartItem['bookId'] == $_GET['bookId']) {
                        $cartItem['quantityInput'] += 1;
                        $found = 1;}   

                   // If the book is not in the cart item, then append the book.
                    elseif ($found == 0) {
                        //add the book
                        echo "new book!";
                        // Connect to Database to get data. Output is $result

                        ****THIS IS THE PART GOING WRONG!*******
                        while ($book = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo "This part is not working well, IT OVERWRITES THE ARRAY!";

                            $cartItem = array('bookId'=>$book['bookId'], 'title'=>$book['title'], 'price'=>$book['price'], 'quantityInput'=>1);
                            $cartItems[$book['bookId']] = $cartItem;

                            echo $cartItems[$book['bookId']]['title'];
                        }
                    }
            }

        } else {
            echo "cart empty";
            $cartItems = array();
            // Add the book into cart item
            // This part I connect with DB to get data, output is $result

            while ($book = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
                $cartItem = array('bookId'=>$book['bookId'], 'title'=>$book['title'], 'price'=>$book['price'], 'quantityInput'=>1);
                $cartItems[$book['bookId']] = $cartItem;
            }
        }
        $_SESSION['cartItems'] = $cartItems;
        print_r($cartItems);
    }
```

I'm confused because I have the key which is `bookId`, and all of item has different id numbers. So it should not overwrite... What am I missing here? How can I fix this problem? Below is the output of the array when I print out the cart item at the end with `print_r($cartItems);`

```
( [2] => Array ( [bookId] => 1 [title] => The Royal Easter [price] => 14.99 [quantityInput] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [bookId] => 1 [title] => The Royal Easter [price] => 14.99 [quantityInput] => 2 )
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. When you say it overwrites the array, what is the exact issue? Do you lose info about other books? Do you lose quantity information? Can you give us a sample of the starting point?

Comment: I see it now... very strange logic. You're executing the `elseif ($found == 0) {` branch every time the id doesn't match (before you eventually find the book). You should only be executing this once, if the book was not found after all the iterations.

Comment: Ahh so I should add something like "break" in the loop so once it doesn't found, it just continue? I'm still confused a little, because I'm only adding one book on top of my previous array. And I'm using ```bookId``` as a key...

Comment: You passed the item as a reference `&$cartItem`, meaning you change its contents despite the id when you later do `$cartItem = array(...`. You shouldn't break out of the loop, you should extract the condition outside the loop.

Comment: Ah right, I had to use it as a reference to change the quantity... you mean I should do something like ```if found then for loop, if not found then for loop``` like this, am I understanding it correct?

Comment: No, not exactly. I'm working on an answer that includes some other side notes to improve your code. It might take a while.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to understand it while you work on it... Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two big culprits in your code. The first one is a flawed control structure:

```
foreach ($cartItems as &$cartItem) {
    if ($cartItem['bookId'] == $_GET['bookId']) {
        $cartItem['quantityInput'] += 1;
        $found = 1;
    }   
    // If the book is not in the cart item, then append the book.
    elseif ($found == 0) {
        // add a whole new book
    }
}
```

Since this is inside a loop, the `elseif` portion will execute *each time* the id doesn't match, until the book is found. If the book was not present, it would execute for *every* element of the cart.

That's where the second culprit comes in. You pass the element as a reference in your loop, meaning any operation over that element would change it. Since you were doing exactly that in the `elseif` branch by assigning it a new value (`$cartItem = ...`), it would ultimately result in it being overwritten.

What you actually need to do is extract the contents of that branch *outside* the loop, because you only want it to run once - if the book was not found:

```
foreach ($cartItems as &$cartItem) {
    // If the book is already in the cart items
    if ($cartItem['bookId'] == $_GET['bookId']) {
        $cartItem['quantityInput'] += 1;
        $found = 1;
        /* Adding a break here would stop the loop once the book was found.
        It would be a logical addition if no special cases exist where
        an item can be added twice independently (seems like that's what
        you're going for, no duplicates in the cart). */
    }
}
// If the book is not in the cart item, then append the book.
if ($found === 0) {
    // everything that was in your elseif branch
}
```

This should solve your issue. But please consider the following improvements to your code...

This code block is repeated twice (both when the book is not found and when the cart is empty):

```
while ($book = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
    $cartItem = array('bookId'=>$book['bookId'], 'title'=>$book['title'], 'price'=>$book['price'], 'quantityInput'=>1);
    $cartItems[$book['bookId']] = $cartItem;
}
```

The sensible thing would be to extract any duplicating code into a function and just call it multiple times. But in your case this duplication can be eliminated. You need the exact same operation in those two cases and you can have the same code execute it:

```
if (isset($_GET['bookId'])) {
    $bookId = $_GET['bookId'];
    $found = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION['cartItems'] ?? [] as $cartItem) {
        if ($cartItem['bookId'] == $bookId) {
            $_SESSION['cartItems'][$bookId]['quantityInput']++;
            $found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($found === 0) {
        // your query code here
        while ($book = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $newCartItem = array_merge($book, ['quantityInput' => 1]);
            $_SESSION['cartItems'][$book['bookId']] = $newCartItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Note several things about the refactored solution:

- I eliminated the check to see if the cart was empty or not. That is really not relevant to your case. All you need to think about is checking if the book exists in the cart. Whether it doesn't because it's empty or simply because other books are in there is all the same for your logic - you just need to append a new item.
- `$_SESSION['cartItems'] ?? []` is the equivalent of `isset($_SESSION['cartItems']) ? $_SESSION['cartItems'] : []` and will tell the loop to use an empty array if there is no cart, which will in turn just skip the loop and go straight to adding the new element.
- I eliminated the passing by reference and modified the session variable directly.
- When adding a new book, I renamed the variable from `$cartItem` to `$newCartItem`. I see it as a good practice not to reuse variable names, it can lead to unexpected results due to accidental reassignments.
- `$newCartItem = array_merge($book, ['quantityInput' => 1]);` does the same thing as your code did with `array('bookId'=>$book['bookId'], 'title'=>$book['title'], 'price'=>$book['price'], 'quantityInput'=>1)` - it uses the same keys and values of the book, just adding quantity to it.